# Fabric js Finding the top most object at a point?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, fabricjs

I have several paths in my canvas, i am trying to draw an image that is dropped on the canvas at certain position and also i want to clip the image based on the area where the image is dropped, I have the position, but there are more objects one below the other, but i just want the top most object at that point.. Is there any built in method that can help me achieve this ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var objs = canvas.getObjects();
var topmost = new Object(); 

   jQuery.each(objs,function(index,val){

        if( val.containsPoint(position) && !(editor.isTargetTransparent(val, canvasX, canvasY)) ){
            //alert("here -->"+val.type);
             // alert(val.get("clipFor"));
            topmost = val;
        }


   });
if(topmost != undefined){
//code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default,

```
var objects = canvas.getObjects();
var top = objects[objects.length - 1];

for (var i = objects.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (objects[i].left === 100 && objects[i].top === 100) {
        top = objects[i];
        break;
    }
}
```

I didn't know any built-in method for this, you check `canvas._objects` property, that's it store all objects in canvas.

Comment: that's fine, but i want to get the topmost object at a point, say at (100,100) ?

Comment: compare it's left, and top propery, is it ok?

Comment: the top most in terms of the z-index, there can be many objects with the same left and top but with different z-indexes!

Answer (score 0):

on farbic js canvas mouse event

```
function mouseEvent(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
}

canvas.on({
    "mouse:up": mouseEvent,
    "mouse:down": mouseEvent
}
```

the `target` in `e` parameter will always be top most object, this method will work on `rotated` object also, just need to make sure the object coords is correctly, can use `object.setCoords()` on `object:modified` event to ensure it is correct.

http://fabricjs.com/events is the sample to inspect event